# How to insert commas between data from array except for last entry?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my output to be so that commas are between all the output items except for the last one. What do I need to do?

```
echo "The following months have 31 days: ";

for ($count=0; $count <= (count($daysInMonth) - 1); $count++) {
  if ($daysInMonth[$count] == 31){
    echo "$months[$count]" . ", ";
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the array $daysInMonth will contain?

Comment: @VishnuJ, it is just the number of days in $daysInMonth as an integer (28, 30, 31, etc.), while $months is the short abbreviation for the month, "Nov, Dec, etc".

Comment: Figured that.  Check answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this. 
Unless you want to manually construct the comma separated string you can use the `implode` function of php.

```
<?php
$longMonths = array();
$daysInMonth = [31,30,31];
$months = ['Jan','Sep','Dec'];

for ($count=0; $count <= (count($daysInMonth) - 1); $count++) {
  if ($daysInMonth[$count] == 31){
    $longMonths[] = $months[$count];
  }
}
echo implode(', ', $longMonths);
```

So here I am storing the values in another array and then writing it as a comma separated string.

Comment: I get this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in (file path) on line 36`. This line is `$longMonths = [];`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
echo "The following months have 31 days: ";

for ($count=0; $count <= (count($daysInMonth) - 1); $count++) {
  if ($daysInMonth[$count] == 31 && $months[$count] != "December"){
    echo "$months[$count]" . ", ";
  }

  if ($daysInMonth[$count] == 31 && $months[$count] == "December") {
    echo "$months[$count]";
  }

}
```